# error when i add UIScrollViewDelegate to UItableviewController swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollviewdelegate

i get an error when i add UIScrollViewDelegate with UITableViewController so i tried every thing i know but nothing worked  `

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
```

help me
(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: What kind of error do you get? What does the message say?

Comment: Are you implementing the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods?

Comment: i get "redundant conformance 'TableViewController' to protocol ' UIScrollViewdeledat'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableViewController has already contains UIScrollViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

If you want to use UIScrollViewDelegate methods, just override it
the do everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewController has already contain UIScrollViewDelegate. You need set

```
tableview.delegate = self
tableview.dataSource = self
```

and after you can using all function of UIScrollViewDelegate protocol